# Add JAR to classpath without stopping the application

Tags: java, jar, runtime, classpath, classloader

I have a Java application running on remote server. I need to add missing JAR file, because now I get `NoClassDefFoundError`. The only difficulty is the fact I cannot stop this application.

Is it possible to add a JAR to classpath without application stop?

I've tried to use `SystemClassLoader` in newly created Java process (as described [here](https://gist.github.com/apemanzilla/28b4fe1f27f2aae9e2c4bd0e4ccac56c)) but it does not work. I guess that different JVM processes have different system class loaders (am I right?). How can I add a JAR without application stop?

Comment: How your application is running? Spring boot? Tomcat?

Comment: Spring boot with embedded Tomcat